# How to reduce left margin on blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

[image]I don't have any experience with `html` or `css`, I recently started my blog: https://nataliaputilova.blogspot.com/2019/09/blog-post_50.html

But you can see there's so much white space on the left, how do I reduce this? I tried googling some stuff about editing the `html` or adding a `css` code, but none of it worked.

This is the `css` I tried, and it didn't look like it changed anythin

```
.content-outer {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: which space the space after the share button  ?

Comment: Both to the left of the share button, and to the right of the share button. The vertical column of white space, in whose center is the share button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the .centered-bottom and post-sidebar class width.

```
.centered-bottom, .centered-top {
    width: 90%;  /*change this */
}
```

if you don't want to have padding for .post-sidebar u can remove it.

```
.post-sidebar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    font: normal 400 14px Montserrat, sans-serif;
    padding-right: 20px; /*Remove this if u don't want to have padding */
    width: 70px;   /*change this */
}
```

[image]

[image]
Final output:
[image: Final img]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the change I am looking to make. Is this in the html code? Also, can you please show in more detail, what is the old(current) value, and to what I need to change it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I also can't find the part with width: 90%, what line of the html is this?

Comment: I editted the width value, reduced from 220 to 60, but now the share button and the date on the top coincide, how do I space them out?

Comment: @BaronYugovich already u have modified something now u just change the width of .post-side bar to 65px or 70px

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sidebar (`.post-sidebbar`) is causing the main content to shift to the right. If it works, you can position it elsewhere so that your content gets more space.

OR

You can override the css of `.centered-bottom`, and add `margin-left: 100px` (Change the number as per your need) to it.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly do I change the .post-sidebar, can you please give me more detailed directions I can execute step by step?

Comment: Option 1: I would check if blogger gives a way to position the sidebar without a code change. I'm not sure for Blogger specifically but usually CMSes allow users to do this. This would be a clean way to do this.
Option 2: Corrected class name to update margin

Comment: I editted the width value, reduced from 220 to 60, but now the share button and the date on the top coincide, how do I space them out?