# Mobile view for blogger is misformatted

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am just a writer, no knowledge of web programming. If you look at my page here: https://nataliaputilova.blogspot.com/2019/09/blog-post_50.html it looks normal.

But if you look at the screenshot from my phone (attached), it does not. What is the issue, how can I fix it? The same problem shows up on both iPhone and Android.

I know in the past it worked, but then I did some changes per [How to reduce left margin on blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835565/how-to-reduce-left-margin-on-blogger) that I think messed up the mobile view. I tried to undo them, but I was poking around a lot and I don't know what I changed exactly

Screenshot from iPhone:
[image]

(there's not even scrollbar at the bottom to move left-right, just this fixed partial view)

I tried to google if it's possible to customize the mobile version, but the results said for these modern themes it should work automatically. But the mobile version is not good, what can I do?

Comment: try removing the `margin-left: -120px;` for `.blog-posts`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this exactly, where do you see this and how do I do it only for mobile view?

Comment: Do I replace it with something, do I delete it completely, and where is it?

Comment: just take it off, it fits neither in a desktop view nor in a mobile view